# PHP script called by ajax can't execute start_session()

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script A that calls session_start() at the top and creates some session variables. 
Then the script makes an ajax call that invokes script B:

```
$("#galleryContent").load("B.php", {op : 'get_thumbs' 
                                   },
                                   function() {
                                    $('.galleryThumb').draggable(thumb_dragOps);  
                                   }
                         s);
```

B needs access to the session variables script A  set up so it does a session_start() to try to get at the variables. But B's session_start() hangs.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Please define "hanging"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to locking; PHP locks the session file while it is writing to it.  To fix this, close the session file when you are done modifying session variables using [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

I have had exactly this problem in the past, and locking was the problem. Just be sure to explicitly tell PHP you're done modifying the session using `session_write_close()`, and you should be fine.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php):

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call `session_write_close()`, but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done.

**Note:** You can also set up a [custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) and avoid this file-locking problem entirely by storing session information in a database. At any kind of scale, this is pretty much a necessity.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I posted a follow-up question on multiple sessions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459497/concurrent-php-sessions if you're interested.