# Concurrent PHP Sessions

Tags: php

Please consider the sequence below.

1. Script A does a session_start() and creates some session variables.
2. Script A does a session_write_close().
3. Script A calls script B with Ajax.
4. Script A continues, since Ajax is asynchronous.
5. Script B does a session_start() and accesses the session variables that script A set up.
6. Script B terminates.

I assume that Script A will block after step 5 if it tries to write any session data while Script B is running.

I assume that Script A can still *read* session variables after step 5. That is, script B executing session_start() does nothing to script A's ability to read session variables.

Do I have that right?

Thanks

Comment: did you already try it??

Comment: I suspect there may be some confusion here. AJAX is a JavaScript thing, not a PHP thing...

Comment: Yes, but AJAX can invoke a PHP script.  See my earlier question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454656/php-script-called-by-ajax-cant-execute-start-session.

Comment: Just don't write long running PHP and you'll never notice this.  For example, at this article, many people are saying like "10 years of PHP and I never knew this." http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/ I never knew it either.

Comment: Actually, I can make it happen at will: omit step 2 above, so script A still has the lock, and step 5 will hang every time.